# Is it possible to extract raw data at the end of a graph?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I'm exploring the Web Audio api in an attempt to try and adapt some aspects of the api into a non-web framework I'm working on (which'll get compiled for the web via Emscripten).

Take the following code:

```
  var audioCtx = new AudioContext();

    // imagine I've called getUserMedia and have the stream from a mic. 
    var source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

    // make a filter to alter the input somehow
    var biquadFilter = audioCtx.createBiquadFilter();
    // imagine we've set some settings

    source.connect(biquadFilter);
```

Say I wanted to get the raw data of the input stream after it's been altered by the BiQuadFilter (or any other filter). Is there any way to do that? As far as I can tell it looks like the AnalyserNode might be what I'm looking for but ideally it'd be great to just pull a buffer off the end of the graph if possible.

Any hints or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways...

## ScriptProcessorNode

You can use a ScriptProcessorNode, which is normally used to process data in your own code, to simply record the raw 32-bit float PCM audio data.

Whether this node outputs anything or not is up to you.  I usually copy the input data to the output out of convenience, but there is a slight overhead to that.

## MediaRecorder

The MediaRecorder can be used to record MediaStreams, both audio and/or video.  First you'll need a MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode.  Once you have that, you can use the MediaRecorder with the resulting stream to record it.

It's important to note that typically with the MediaRecorder, you're recording compressed audio with a lossy codec.  This is essentially the purpose of the MediaRecorder.  However, support for PCM in WebM has recently been added by at least Chrome.  Just use `{type: 'audio/webm;codecs=pcm'}` when instantiating your MediaRecorder.

(I haven't tested this yet, but I suspect you're going to end up with 16-bit PCM, not 32-bit float which is used internally in the Web Audio API.)

Comment: Didn't know Chrome added support for PCM codecs. But your answer read a bit as if it were a WebM standard, is it really? Also, I don't think FF does support it, so you may want to nuance this anyway.

Comment: hmm I don't think MediaRecorder will work - audio will have to be processed in near real-time. ScriptProcessorNode  did occur to me but I was hesitant given that it's marked for deprecation but looks like that's probably the logical path at the moment. 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JosephChow AudioWorklet will replace it, which allows audio processing to get off the main thread, but ScriptProcessorNode isn't going anywhere any time soon.  Just keep an eye on it over the next few years and switch once browser support is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

here is a web page just save it `mycode.html` then give its file location to your browser ... it will prompt to gain access to your microphone ... take notice of `createMediaStreamSource` as well as where raw audio buffer is accessed then printed to browser console log ... essentially you define callback functions which make available the raw audio upon each Web Audio API event loop iteration - enjoy

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>capture microphone then show time & frequency domain output</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

var webaudio_tooling_obj = function () {

    var audioContext = new AudioContext();

    console.log("audio is starting up ...");

    var BUFF_SIZE_RENDERER = 16384;
    var SIZE_SHOW = 3; // number of array elements to show in console output

    var audioInput = null,
    microphone_stream = null,
    gain_node = null,
    script_processor_node = null,
    script_processor_analysis_node = null,
    analyser_node = null;

    if (!navigator.getUserMedia)
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

    if (navigator.getUserMedia){

        navigator.getUserMedia({audio:true}, 
            function(stream) {
                start_microphone(stream);
            },
            function(e) {
                alert('Error capturing audio.');
            }
            );

    } else { alert('getUserMedia not supported in this browser.'); }

    // ---

    function show_some_data(given_typed_array, num_row_to_display, label) {

        var size_buffer = given_typed_array.length;
        var index = 0;

        console.log("__________ " + label);

        if (label === "time") {

            for (; index < num_row_to_display && index < size_buffer; index += 1) {

                var curr_value_time = (given_typed_array[index] / 128) - 1.0;

                console.log(curr_value_time);
            }

        } else if (label === "frequency") {

            for (; index < num_row_to_display && index < size_buffer; index += 1) {

                console.log(given_typed_array[index]);
            }

        } else {

            throw new Error("ERROR - must pass time or frequency");
        }
    }

    function process_microphone_buffer(event) {

        var i, N, inp, microphone_output_buffer;

        // not needed for basic feature set
        // microphone_output_buffer = event.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0); // just mono - 1 channel for now
    }

    function start_microphone(stream){

        gain_node = audioContext.createGain();
        gain_node.connect( audioContext.destination );

        microphone_stream = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        microphone_stream.connect(gain_node); 

        script_processor_node = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(BUFF_SIZE_RENDERER, 1, 1);
        script_processor_node.onaudioprocess = process_microphone_buffer;

        microphone_stream.connect(script_processor_node);

        // --- enable volume control for output speakers

        document.getElementById('volume').addEventListener('change', function() {

            var curr_volume = this.value;
            gain_node.gain.value = curr_volume;

            console.log("curr_volume ", curr_volume);
        });

        // --- setup FFT

        script_processor_analysis_node = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);
        script_processor_analysis_node.connect(gain_node);

        analyser_node = audioContext.createAnalyser();
        analyser_node.smoothingTimeConstant = 0;
        analyser_node.fftSize = 2048;

        microphone_stream.connect(analyser_node);

        analyser_node.connect(script_processor_analysis_node);

        var buffer_length = analyser_node.frequencyBinCount;

        var array_freq_domain = new Uint8Array(buffer_length);
        var array_time_domain = new Uint8Array(buffer_length);

        console.log("buffer_length " + buffer_length);

        script_processor_analysis_node.onaudioprocess = function() {

            // get the average for the first channel
            analyser_node.getByteFrequencyData(array_freq_domain);
            analyser_node.getByteTimeDomainData(array_time_domain);

            // draw the spectrogram
            if (microphone_stream.playbackState == microphone_stream.PLAYING_STATE) {

                show_some_data(array_freq_domain, SIZE_SHOW, "frequency");
                show_some_data(array_time_domain, SIZE_SHOW, "time"); // store this to record to aggregate buffer/file
            }
        };
    }

}(); //  webaudio_tooling_obj = function()

</script>

</head>
<body>

    <p>Volume</p>
    <input id="volume" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.0"/>

</body>
</html>
```

a variation of above approach will allow you to replace microphone with your own logic to synthesize the audio curve again with ability to access the audio buffer

Answer (score 0):

On other alternative is to create your graph with an `OfflineAudioContext`.  You do have to know before hand how much data you want to capture, but if you do, you'll get your result faster than real-time, usually.

You'll get the raw PCM data so you can save it or analyze it, further modify it, or whatever.